為什麼 "pointer" 被翻譯成 "指標" in traditional Chinese？
According to wordreference, the possible translations of "pointer" in prior to the Computer Science notion are:

指示杆, 指示棒 (pointing stick, rod)
指示犬 (pointer dog)

And, in reverso the context translation shows that "pointer" can also be:

指示器, 指针 (gauge or compass pointer)

However, when translating the Computer Science concept of "pointer" to traditional Chinese, someone decided to use the word "指標" instead of anything listed above. So I wonder what's the possible reason behind this?

What would you expect and why? How does this differ? Your thinking would help anyone looking to answer the question. I could assuming you would expect: "指示标" instead. I could offer the reasoning that the main issue might be that "指示标" sounds more like "road markings." But this would just be taking stabs in the dark without understanding your thought process.

Yes, I am expecting something like "指示标" or "指针", where the latter is the Simplified Chinese translation. The reason is that "pointer" in CS is a variable that stores memory address, which has similar functionality as the road sign or pointing rod that locate the location of another object. "指標" seems more like a economic indicator, which doesn’t seem fit in this context.

指针 is the correct way to say pointer in a CS context, see the mainland Chinese version of the wiki page you linked above: https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E6%8C%87%E6%A8%99_(%E9%9B%BB%E8%85%A6%E7%A7%91%E5%AD%B8). The issue really lies in the difference between 国语 (Taiwanese Standard Mandarin) and 普通话 (Mainland Mandarin).

Pointer (computer science) - A pointer is a variable that stores/holds the address of another variable.

指 - pointing
標 - a mark, symbol, label, sign
Now you should know why it makes sense as a computer science terminology.

指标: (production)​ target, quota, index, indicator, sign, signpost, (computing)​ pointer
The pointer variable "points" at a target address, that's why it has this Chinese name.
The value of var may change, P then shows the new value of var.
Python doesn't claim to have pointer variables, but it has ids for objects.
In this code, b "points at" or "targets" a. Change a and b is changed:
make a Python list
a = [1]
id(a) # 138593434158592
b = a # this just assigns b to "point" at a, the ids are the same,
unless you use .copy() to create a new list
id(b) # 138593434158592 # same as a
change a and b changes
a[0] = 10
b[0] # returns 10
Didn't know # creates headings in mark-up!
